# Integration a 2D Gaussian distribution over a line, what is the meaning of that and how to achieve that?

Tags: probability, integration, covariance, maximum-likelihood

my problem is to find the best error model for a sensor. I got measurement(points) and reference surface(line segments) and I want a error model(2D gaussian distribustion) which gives the maximum likelihood. What I did is that I integrate the 2D gaussian distribution over a line segment$$ \int_{ \mathbf{p_1}}^{\mathbf{p_2}}  \frac{1}{2 \pi  \sqrt{  det \Sigma } }  e^{- \frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{ \mu })^T \Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{ \mu }) }   \, d \mathbf{p} $$
where $\mathbf{p} = \left[\begin{matrix}
x  \\
y 
\end{matrix}\right]  $ is the point on a reference line, $\mu$ is the measurement point and $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of the error model(2d Gaussian).
My first question would be does this even make sense to integrate over a line?
The second question is that since $\mathbf{p}$ is on a line, I want to map $\mathbf{p} \in (\mathbf{p_1}, \mathbf{p_2})$ to t$\in(0, 1)$. Then the Integral would be $$ \int_{0}^{1} P(\mathbf{p(t)}) \mathbf{p}^{'} (t) \, dt $$
what is this $\mathbf{p}^{'} (t)$? should it be the distance from $\mathbf{p_1}$ to $\mathbf{p_2}$? what if I need to integral over $t \in (0.2, 0.8)$, does this 
$\mathbf{p}^{'} (t)$ also change, since the integral intervl changes?
I would really appreciate that if someone can help me...

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. The equation of line segment is $t\mathbf{p_2} + (1-t)\mathbf{p_2}$ or $t\mathbf{p_1} + (1-t)\mathbf{p_1}$ , $t \in [0,1]$ depending the direction you want to sweep segment. For the meaning, first consider that by integrating, the function you have at hand is not normalized. Are you trying to use conditioning? have you studied the material here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability carefully? BTW, the likelihood of observation is not a conditional probability, thus no worries.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald thank you very much for your help. I still don't quite get it. I know how to map the $p$ to $t$. what I want to know is whether the integral of a 2d gaussian probability density function over a line makes any sense and does this represent the likelihood, and how can I calculate this $\mathbf{p}^{'} (t)$.