# likelihood of a line on a plane

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

Assume we have an observation(one point) of a line segment on a plane and the distribution of the observation is a 2D Gaussian distribution. The line in the figure is a possible line segment according to the real segment.
My question is what is the likelihood of the possible line in this case? It's that the integral of the 2D Gaussian probability density function over the line segment?

[Figure: Observation and the line segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D74T.png)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This is rather unclear. If the observed point has a Gaussian distribution, how is it related to the line segment? We need to know the prior distribution of the line segment parameters, and of the point along the line segment; that the prior distribution of points they lead to is Gaussian doesn't help much (and seems implausible, by the way).

Comment: @joriki thank you for the comment. The observed point is a measurement from an ultrasonic sensor and the sensor is implemented to sense a wall which is the line in the figure. What I am trying to do is to find the best parameter of the error model for the sensor ( a Gaussian distribution) which gives the maximum likelihood. does this make the question more clear?

Comment: Not really (at least for me). I don't see how you want to do this without any model for the line segment. I guess we can assume that the orientation is uniformly distributed, but what about the length and position? Neither can be uniformly distributed, so you need to have some other prior for them. But perhaps I'm just completely misunderstanding what you're trying to do. Perhaps you can point to an example where the sort of thing you envisage has been done for another problem?

Comment: I guess you could have an improper uniform prior for the length and position (though that doesn't seem terribly realistic if you're trying to sense a wall) – but I think in that case the maximum likelihood estimate would degenerate to a zero-length segment at the position of the observed point, which is probably not what you want... (You also need a prior for the position of the observed point along the segment; but here a uniform distribution would be unproblematic.)

Comment: Hi @joriki, this is the problem I asked before but no one answer(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517008/integration-a-2d-gaussian-distribution-over-a-line-what-is-the-meaning-of-that). In the real situation, I get lots of measurements of the wall. What I have is the reference data of the wall(the line segment) and measurements. What I am trying to investigate is the best suitable error model (a 2d Gaussian) which makes the reference line segment have the largest probability. I don't know if this is helpful for a better understanding

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand that other post, either. I think you have to take more care to use terminology precisely. What do you mean by "reference surface (line segments)" and by "the reference data of the wall (the line segment)"? It would help if you make this a lot more explicit, showing precisely and concretely which data you have, perhaps using an example. In that other post, you seem to be integrating over a specific line segment, but it's unclear which line segment this is.